# Editing Annotations In VSphere Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, vsphere, powercli

I need to be able to edit the Annotations of VMs from powershell(ps) as will be editing many at once [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so75V.png). I found "AvailibleField" after getting VM view in ps [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTCNN.png) but not sure how to edit these. Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the Get/Set-Annotation cmdlets: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI651/html/Set-Annotation.html

Example:

```html
PS C:\Users\kruddy> Get-VM file02 | select CustomFields

CustomFields
------------
{[CompanyName, ]}


PS C:\Users\kruddy> Get-VM file02 | Get-Annotation

AnnotatedEntity Name                 Value
--------------- ----                 -----
file02          CompanyName


PS C:\Users\kruddy> Set-Annotation -Entity (Get-VM file02) -CustomAttribute CompanyName -Value TempCorp -Confirm:$false

AnnotatedEntity Name                 Value
--------------- ----                 -----
file02          CompanyName          TempCorp


PS C:\Users\kruddy> Get-VM file02 | Get-Annotation

AnnotatedEntity Name                 Value
--------------- ----                 -----
file02          CompanyName          TempCorp


PS C:\Users\kruddy> Get-VM file02 | select CustomFields

CustomFields
------------
{[CompanyName, TempCorp]}


PS C:\Users\kruddy>
```